# <iframe> button to main

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this kind of code:

**`iframe.html`:**

```
<div id="w">
<div id="a">
 ...
</div>
<div id="b" style="display:none">
 ...
</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="button" class="b open">Change</a>
```

**`main.html`:**

```
...
<div id="con">
        <iframe src="http://localhost/iframe.html" scrolling="no" id="myiframe">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>
<div id="show" style="display:none">
Hello WOrld!
</div>
```

My JavaScript inside the `<iframe>`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#button").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
                $(this).addClass('close');
                $('#a').fadeOut(200);
                $("#b").fadeIn(200);
 }else{
$("a#button").css({"margin-top":""});
                $(this).removeClass('close');
                $(this).addClass('open');
                $("#b").fadeOut(200);
                $('#a').fadeIn(200);
}

  });
});
```

I try to insert this code in the `<iframe>` JavaScript:

```
....
 $("a#button").click(function(){
    $("#show").css({"display":"block", "background":"green"});
....
}
```

However, it won't work because the JavaScript code is inside the `<iframe>` and it cannot see the `#show` `<div>`.

Is there any way using JavaScript or jQuery that when I click the `#button` in the `<iframe>` that it will reflect the `#show` `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $("a#button").click(function(){
   $('#show', window.parent.document).css({"display":"block", "background":"green"});
   ... 
 }
```

OR

```
parent.top.$("#show").css({"display":"block", "background":"green"});
```